# How do chain python generator expressions with filtering?

Tags: generator, for-comprehension

I am trying to chain generators so I can process a large CSV file as a stream of lines rather than doing each single operation in a batch.

This way, I can delay each iteration of each step, avoiding loading an entire data set in memory.

Generator expressions work fine except if I put try to filter the output with an if statement.

This works: and only one iteration is consumed at a time

```
file_iterable = open("myfile.csv")
parsed_csv_iterable = (parse_i(i) for i in file_iterable)
```

then I can get a line at a time by calling `next()` on the resulting iterable. However, if I do this

```
file_iterable = open("myfile.csv")
parsed_csv_iterable = (parse_i(i) for i in file_iterable if parse_i(i)[0] in [1,2,3])
```

Then, the iterator keeps running until is exhausted. Why? What's the workaround?